# ChartJS v3 Customer Time Scale, clear xaxis gap

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart that I've build using Chart.js. The data is loading fine, it's based on a time scale which is also working. I've used the ticks callback function to filter out ticks that shouldn't appear, outside of business hours. However now I have these massive gaps and I can't seem to find a setting or configuration to eliminate them. Does anyone have any experience with the type of scenario? I've played with autoskip and spangaps, neither of which solve it. Ideally the gaps should be gone so they're just next to each other.

[image]

Comment: What you would ideally want is axes breaks, a feature not yet implemented in chart.js. You may try reverting to category axis for x or creating a [custom axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/developers/axes.html); a possible concrete solution is contingent on your posting a runnable example.

Comment: Thank you, are there any good examples of how to configure that? I looked at the link but it doesn't seem to address setting the labels or ranges. It's unfortunate that it gives you the ability to customize the axis but not enough to clear the gaps.

Comment: I'll try to set up a minimal example

Comment: That'd be awesome. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you haven't started on it yet don't worry about it. I decided to go a different, less granular, route. If you do still post something I'm sure people would appreciate it as there's not much documentation on that process. Thanks again for your help

Comment: OK, so here it is, the example I mentioned; first a piece of code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayzm6r3s/) illustrating the problem - time data with gaps; then a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k9ry64u/) illustrating how to approach the solution by building a custom time axis with breaks, or rather illustrating how complicated it is to do so. **Note**: this is just an example, there are a number of missing features and loopholes, don't use in production!